# Getting Errors while adding CouchBaseLite to iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, couchbase, couchbase-lite

Hi I am trying to add Couchbase Lite framework to iOS applciation.
I added frameworks which are needed. But I'm getting linker errors.

I am getting error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

Please find the following attachment regarding error.

[image: Error Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding libc++.tbd framework to the application.

I got help from below article.

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/26-errors-when-building-ios-swift-project/9441/2